# VBA code to select cells in a row from an active cell till the last cell with data. There are empty cells in between active cell and last data cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count all empty and non empty cells from a reference cell / active cell in a row. For example, I have data from cell H46 to S46. In between H46 to S46, there are merged cells as well. How can I select all cells from H46 to S46? I want to later count these number of cells and use this a loop counter. Data range is not fixed. In some sheets, last cell greater (eg AA46) or lower than S46 (eg Q46). But last cell always has some value in it (number). I tried below code:

```
  Sub Select_all_empty_nonEmpty_cells()

  Range("H46", Range("I46").End(xlToRight)).Select

  End Sub
```

The code above stops at the first set of merged cells

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Range("H46", Cells(46, Cells(46, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Select
```

It locates the first non empty cell from the last column.

Comment: Simplify with `Range("H46", Cells(46, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select`.

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008. It of course works. I made it more generic rather than hard coded: 'Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select'

Comment: Thank you @Blakc cat. I made it more generic rather than hard coded: 'Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select'

Answer (score 0):

A function to find the desired range and a Sub to loop through the cells of the range that has merged cells

```
'FIND THE RANGE FROM CELL TO THE LAST NON EMPTY CELL IN ROW
Public Function findTheRange(fromCell As Range) As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Long
   Set ws = fromCell.Worksheet
   For c = ws.UsedRange.Columns.CountLarge To fromCell.Column Step -1
      If ws.Cells(fromCell.Row, c).Value2 <> "" Then
         Set findTheRange = ws.Range(fromCell, ws.Cells(fromCell.Row, c))
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
End Function

'LOOP IN THE RANGE WITCH HAVE MERGED CELLS
Sub loopInRangeWithMergedCells(rng As Range)
   Dim cll As Range
   If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   For Each cll In rng
      If cll.Address = cll.MergeArea.Cells(1).Address Then
         'your commands here

      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Maybe you want the returned range to include only the first cell of the merged cells

```
'FIND THE DESIRED RANGE WITH REFERENCE ONLY TO THE FIRST CELL OF EACH GROUP OF MERGED CELLS
'WITH THE RETURNED RANGE YOU CAN ITERATE WITHOUT CHECK (If cll.Address = cll.MergeArea.Cells(1).Address Then...)
Public Function rangeWithMergedAsOneCell(fromCell As Range) As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Long, lastAddrr As String, tCell As String, allStrRng As String
   Set ws = fromCell.Worksheet
   For c = ws.UsedRange.Columns.CountLarge To fromCell.Column Step -1
      With ws.Cells(fromCell.Row, c)
         If ws.Cells(fromCell.Row, c).Value2 <> "" Or tCell <> "" Then
            If .Address = .MergeArea.Cells(1).Address Then
               If tCell = "" Then
                  tCell = .Address
                  If c = fromCell.Column Then
                     allStrRng = tCell & IIf(allStrRng = "", "", ",") & allStrRng
                  End If
               Else
                  If c = fromCell.Column Then
                     If tCell = "" Or tCell <> .Address Then
                        allStrRng = .Address & ":" & tCell & IIf(allStrRng = "", "", ",") & allStrRng
                     Else
                        allStrRng = tCell & IIf(allStrRng = "", "", ",") & allStrRng
                     End If
                  End If
               End If
            Else
               If tCell <> "" Then
                  If tCell = lastAddrr Then
                     allStrRng = tCell & IIf(allStrRng = "", "", ",") & allStrRng
                  Else
                     allStrRng = lastAddrr & ":" & tCell & IIf(allStrRng = "", "", ",") & allStrRng
                  End If
                  tCell = ""
               End If
            End If
         End If
         lastAddrr = .Address
      End With
   Next
   Debug.Print allStrRng
   Set rangeWithMergedAsOneCell = ws.Range(allStrRng)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I hope it works. I made little change to your code.

```
Sub Select_all_empty_nonEmpty_cells()

  Range("H46", Range("AAA46").End(xlToLeft)).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: There are cells beyond (to the right of) column `AAA`. If you want to hard-code it, do it properly: `Range("H46", Range("XFD46").End(xlToLeft)).Select`. But this will fail in older versions since the last column was column `IV` hence the use of `Columns.Count` is superior.